# how to use substr in awk?

Tags: unix, awk, substring, substr

I have strings that look like this

```
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/1
/foo/bar/baz
/foo/bar/baz/1
```

I want to be able to chop off the end only if it's a number.
For example, `/foo/bar` stays the same, but `/foo/bar/1` becomes `/foo/bar`

How to I do this in awk?

Comment: There are a few methods you could use.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`, you can try it as:

```
awk '{sub(/\/[0-9]+$/,"");print}' filename
```

For your input output comes as:

```
/foo/bar
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/baz
/foo/bar/baz
```

If you want to use `substr` function in awk:

```
awk '{line=substr($0,1,index($0,/[0-9]/)-2); if(length(line)==0)line=$0; print line}' filename
```

Using `sed`, you can do it as:

```
while read line; do echo $line | sed 's/\/[0-9]\+$//'; done < filename
```

Comment: I tried running both of the awk expressions you wrote and I'm getting an error...


awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: I'm using `awk version 20110810`

Comment: @Brian check if this works `awk '{print $(sub(/\/[0-9]+$/,""));}'`

Comment: Still same error. I tried this on Linux and it works there, but not my Unix machine.

Comment: @Brian in the awk command in my answer, use `awk` instead of `mawk`. So the command should be: `mawk '{sub(/\/[0-9]+$/,"");print}' filename` or `mawk '{line=substr($0,1,index($0,/[0-9]/)-2); if(length(line)==0)line=$0; print line}' filename`

Answer (score 0):

I guess your number is at the end of your expression.
In that case the code below will work, if otherwise please let me know.

`echo "/foo/bar/1" | awk -F"[0-9]+" '{print $1;}'`

the code above will print: `/foo/bar/`

Answer (score 0):

So many ways, but

```
sub(/\/[0-9]+$/, "");
```

might be the easiest.